Google Maps drawn Polygon looses draggable functionality on mobile
Google Map with drawing manager allows one to draw polygons. One can drag the polygon perfectly on desktop but it's not possible on mobile.
This seems to be a bug because SOMETIMES it IS draggable and sometimes not. When one adds a polygon from existing coordinates it can be dragged on mobile, but cannot  be dragged if one draws it directly.
https://jsfiddle.net/Milenoi2/069yfqsk/1/
I added a setOptions method on they polygon after drawing it but it is not consistently draggable. Sometimes one can drag a drawn polygon but not always. I also tried to using with z-index and removing and adding gestureHandling but those had no effect.
var map;

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({

        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            strokeWeight: 1,
            strokeColor: '#ff0000',
        }
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {

        // Get overlay paths
        var paths = event.overlay.getPaths();
        
        // Remove overlay from map
        event.overlay.setMap(null);
        
        // Disable drawingManager
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

        // Create Polygon
        createPolygon(paths);
    });
}

function createPolygon(paths) {
    
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        fillColor: '#ffff00',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeColor: '#0000ff',
        editable: true,
        draggable: true,
         clickable: true,
        paths: paths,
        map: map
    });
}

initialize();


Could you please raise an issue in Google Public Issue Tracker?
